# Angulajs ng-options from a json with child object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to populate an angularjs ng-options with a json file that has child object, but i am finding it difficult getting it to work.

This is my controller script

```
 inmomentControllerNameSpace.controller('userController', function($scope, $http, $q){
 $scope.countryUserCode = {};

 $http.get("js/countryCode.json").success(function(data){

    $scope.countryUserCode = data;
                $scope.tel = 'show';
            })
     })
})
```

My HTML Code

```
<select data-ng-options="name.countryUserCode for d in countryUserCode" data-ng-model="selectedCode"></select></select>
```

My Json File

```
{
"af": {
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "phoneCode": "93"
},
"al": {
    "name": "Albania",
    "phoneCode": "355"
},
"dz": {
    "name": "Algeria",
    "phoneCode": "213"
}
}
```

What i intend to achieve is to have the name appear in the option label and the phone code appear in the option.

I will be glad if anyone can help me thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax for ngOptions:

```
<select data-ng-options="country.phoneCode as country.name for (isoCode, country) in countryUserCode" data-ng-model="selectedCode"></select>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/7csZXkmY430LTLhf5D7g?p=preview